# Cannot implement operator==() to compare a custom class object to a QString

Tags: c++, qt, operator-overloading, qt5.5

I have created the following class:

```
class videodup
{
public:
    videodup(QString vid = "", int m_a = 0, int m_b = 0);
    ~videodup() {}
    QString video;
    bool operator==(const QString &str) const { return video == str; }
bool operator==(const videodup &dup) const {return video == dup.video;}
    QList<matchPair> matches;
};

videodup::videodup(QString vid = "", int m_a = 0, int m_b = 0)
{
    video = vid;
    matches.append(matchPair(m_a, m_b));
}
```

I thought it would allow me to use a `QString` in `QList::contains()` but it is giving me an error:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.5.1_2/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qlist.h:981: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('videodup' and 'const videodup')
        if (i->t() == t)
            ~~~~~~ ^  ~
/Users/phire/Documents/workspace/VideoTwin/matchpair.h:30: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const videodup' to 'QString &' for 1st argument
    bool operator==(QString &str) { return video == str; }
         ^
```

The offending line is:

```
if (frame.videomatches.contains(vid))
```

here is the code explaining the line above

```
struct frm
{
    QString file;
    int position;
    cv::Mat descriptors;
    QList<videodup> videomatches;
};
QList<frm> frames;

void MainWindow::findDupes(frm &frame)
{
    QString file = frame.file;
    UMat mat = frame.descriptors.getUMat(cv::ACCESS_RW);
    UMat indices;
    UMat dists;
    if (!mat.isContinuous() || mat.empty())
        return;
    QTime timestamp(0,0,0,0);
    timestamp = timestamp.addMSecs(frame.position);
    try
    {
        mat = mat.reshape(1,1);
        index.knnSearch(mat,indices,dists,5);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        qWarning() << "index search failure" << e.err.c_str() << e.msg.c_str();
    }
    catch (exception& e)
    {
        qWarning() << "index search failure" << e.what();
    }
//    qDebug() <<  "indices cols" << indices.cols << "dists cols" << dists.cols;
    db.transaction();
    QSqlQuery matches(db);
    QStringList tempmatches;
    Mat indicesMat = indices.getMat(cv::ACCESS_READ);
    Mat distsMat = dists.getMat(cv::ACCESS_READ);

    for (int i = 0; i < indicesMat.cols; i++)
    {
        if (indicesMat.at<int>(0,i) == -1 || distsMat.at<int>(0,i) > 12800)
            continue;
        try
        {
            QTime matchtime(0,0,0,0);
            int matchms = frames.at( indicesMat.at<int>(0,i)).position;
            QString vid = frames.at( indicesMat.at<int>(0,i)).file;
            matchtime = matchtime.addMSecs(matchms);
            int temp = distsMat.at<int>(0,i);
            tempmatches.append(QString::number( indicesMat.at<int>(0,i)));
            if (frame.videomatches.contains(vid))
            {
                matchPair pair(frame.position, indicesMat.at<int>(0,i));
                frame.videomatches[ frame.videomatches.indexOf(vid) ].matches.append(pair);
            }
            else
            {
                frame.videomatches.append(videodup(vid,frame.position, indicesMat.at<int>(0,i)));
            }
//            qDebug() << frame.file << "frame"<<  timestamp.toString("hh:mm:ss") << "match at"<< vid << matchtime.toString("hh:mm:ss") << "distance" << temp;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            qWarning() << "failure in indices" << e.err.c_str() << e.msg.c_str() << e.func.c_str();
        }
        catch (exception &e)
        {
            qWarning() << "failure in indices" << e.what();
        }
    }
    QString temp(tempmatches.join(","));
    matches.prepare("UPDATE frames SET matches = :matches WHERE file = :file AND position = :position");
    matches.bindValue(":matches",temp);
    matches.bindValue(":file",frame.file);
    matches.bindValue(":position",frame.position);
    if (!matches.exec())
        qWarning() << "couldn't add matches to frame in database";
    db.commit();
}
```

How can I make my custom class comparable to a `QString`?

Comment: Neal is that the same code, or has it changed since? You removed the paste very unfortunately, again I've forgotten (and it's not clear in the first place) what `frame`, `frame.videomatches` and `vid` are. That matters.

Comment: tried to only paste the relevant bits http://pastebin.com/8WP8jT5P

Comment: OK, I see your problem, thinking how to circumvent it. With STL it would be easily possible, with Qt I need to think a bit.

Comment: alright guys adding the extra operator==() definition did it, so who said that first?

Comment: Honestly I think it was Michael, I got lost while deciphering the exact sequence of operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is complaining about trying to compare a 'videodup' and 'const videodup'.

You just need to define a `bool operator==(const videodup &) const` function.

`QString` is mentioned in the error because that's the only type that `videodup::operator==()` accepts, so the compiler tries to do a conversion to `QString` but finds that it can't.

Comment: Michael, I somehow see it the other way round. `bool QList::contains(const T & value) const;` means that `QList` is only going to accept `videodup` and is trying to convert the `QString` into that. Am I wrong?

Comment: Also, I'd be grateful if you looked at my call analysis above, if I got that correct.

Comment: I'm just going by what the error messages say.  The first one says that `qlist.h:981` is trying to compare a `videodup` and a `const videodup` object.  The second one says that `matchpair.h:30` is trying to convert a `const videodup` object to a `QString&` so it can call `bool operator==(QString &str)` but it can't perform the conversion.

Comment: How does the second statement then coincide with the fact that `operator==` wants a `T` (a `videodup`)? Why does it try to convert the other way round? Problem is (I understand your flow of thought!) there is no `const videodup` there by looking at the code, there only may be a `videodup` created from a `QString`.

Comment: The error messages indicate that the `QList` contains objects of `videodup` - not `QString` objects.  The `Qlist` code it trying to compare a couple of `videodup` objects but can't do that directly because there's no `operator==()` that deals with them directly.  The compiler does see the `operator==()` that takes a `QString` and therefore tries to convert but can't.  I think that if the OP showed the declarations for `frame`, `frame.videomatches`, and `vid` from the "offending line" all this might be more clear.

Comment: Why, they're all in the pastebin link, can you see it in the comments below the actual question post?

Comment: So looking at the pastebin tells us that `frame.videomatches` is a `QList<videodup>`.  When `frame.videomatches.contains(vid)` is called, the compiler converts the `QString` `vid` argument to a `videodup` argument (since `class videodup` has a constructor that will do that).  The rest is as I said before.

Comment: Great, so I guessed right about the implicit conversion. Thank you for the help. This area is my weakness. Edit: Oh so it tries all the `operator==()`'s regardless of the type right? Didn't know it worked that way.

Comment: I added the line.     `bool operator==(const videodup &dup) const {return video == dup.video;}` but now get the error `/Users/phire/Documents/workspace/VideoTwin/mainwindow.cpp:394: error: no viable conversion from 'QString' to 'const videodup'
            if (frame.videomatches.contains(vid))
                                            ^~~`

Comment: Try changing
`if (frame.videomatches.contains(vid))`
to
`if (frame.videomatches.contains(videodup(vid)))`

Comment: that did it I think, I had another issue that was confusing this too, but it works now

Comment: Which one exactly, just defining the comparison operator?

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is what I think is gong on here. First, and foremost,

```
bool QList::contains(const T & value) const;
```

This function wants (a) an object of type `T` (the type it stores) or (b) an object of type `R` that can be somehow converted to `T`. How exactly? By means of a conversion operator `R::T()`or a c'tor or `R` that takes a `T`: `R:R(T&)`. See, you have exactly the latter available. `videodup::videodup(QString&, int=default, int=default)`.

And here it the actual problem:

Once the compiler successfully converts `QString` into `videodup` by the means of the aforementioned constructor, it wants to invoke `videodup::operator==(const videodup&)`, as required by the `QList::contains(const T&)` function, and can't find one. Hence you need to uncomment and implement the `videodup::operator==(const videodup&)`, just as Michael says.

Edit:

I also think that to avoid this implicit conversion, we can use the STL `std::find<Iterator, T>` function, and leverage `videodup::operator==(const QString&)`. To do so, just replace

```
if (frame.videomatches.contains(vid)) {
```

with

```
const auto &matches = frame.videomatches;
if (std::find(matches.cbegin(), matches.cend(), vid) != matches.cend()) {
```

I'm quite sure that this is going to use the existing operator directly, avoiding the unnecessary conversion.